# Clear the in memory database after every testcase

Tags: java, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am using hsqldb for testing some of the data access layer in Java. I have certain test cases like 100 around. I create a in memory database and then insert some values in the table so that with my test case i can load it, but the problem is for every test case i need to clear the in memory database, only the values not the tables.

Is it possible, one thing is i need to manually delete the rows from the table and is there some thing else I can use.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Java test framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) in unit-tests, you can specify that DbUnit should perform a clean-and-insert operation before every test to ensure that the contents of the database are in a valid state before every test. This can be done in a manner similar to the one below:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    logger.info("Performing the setup of test {}", testName.getMethodName());
    IDatabaseConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = getConnection();
        IDataSet dataSet = getDataSet();
        //The following line cleans up all DbUnit recognized tables and inserts and test data before every test.
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataSet);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Closes the connection as the persistence layer gets it's connection from elsewhere
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Note that it is always recommended to perform any setup activities in a `@Before` setup method, rather than in a `@After` teardown method. The latter indicates that you are creating new database objects in a method being tested, which IMHO does not exactly lend easily to testable behavior. Besides, if you are cleaning up after a test, to ensure that a second test runs correctly, then any such cleanup is actually a part of the setup of the second test, and not a teardown of the first.

The alternative to using DbUnit is to start a new transaction in your `@Before` setup method, and to roll it back in the `@After` teardown method. This would depend on how your data access layer is written.

If your data access layer accepts `Connection` objects, then your setup routine should create them, and turn off auto-commit. Also, there is an assumption that your data access layer will not invoke `Connection.commit`. Assuming the previous, you can rollback the transaction using `Connection.rollback()` in your teardown method.

With respect to transaction control, the below snippet demonstrates how one would do it using JPA for instance:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    logger.info("Performing the setup of test {}", testName.getMethodName());
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    // Starts the transaction before every test
    em.getTransaction.begin();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception
{
    logger.info("Performing the teardown of test {}", testName.getMethodName());
    if (em != null)
    {
        // Rolls back the transaction after every test
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Similar approaches would have to be undertaken for other ORM frameworks or even your custom persistence layer, if you have written one.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use [HSQLDB transactions](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sessions-chapt.html#sqlgeneral_trans_cc-sect)?

Before every test, start a new transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

After every test, roll it back:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

This would also allow you to have some permanent data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your test framework, it is possible to execute a delete call after each test. In Junit the annotation is [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) and a method with this annotation will be run after each [[`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html)] method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Truncate Query for the Destroy Database Memory or this link can be helpful to you.

http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/InMemoryBackEndPrimer